# Pass instance of class module in sub procedure

Tags: excel, vba, class, procedure

I have a class module called game which calls a sub from another class module called gameUi. This sub receives an instance of a class module called board.

game class module:

```
Private board As New board
Private gameUi As New gameUi

Sub Init()
    gameUi.Init board
End Sub
```

gameUi class module:

```
Private board As board

Sub Init(gameBoard As board)
    board = gameBoard
End Sub
```

I keep getting this error and I can't understand why:

[image]

I have other sub / functions in other class modules that receive parameters such as Integers and Strings but I don't get this error there. It seems it just happens when I pass an instance of a class module.

I've tried passing another class module to the sub and it happens the same. Also tried adding the ByVal or ByRef options but the result is the error shown.

If anybody could help I would be very appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `Set board = gameBoard` ?

Comment: that was it, but I only have to use it when I'm dealing with objects? because I can go without the set when its primitive types

Comment: then add a test for type

Comment: how so? using the set for a primitive type as well?

Comment: No. I mean use inbuilt VBA functions to test for datatype and branched logic based on return.